# Set rooms for users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to resolve a problem but I don't find the solution. This is my code:

```
class User < AR::Base
  belongs_to :room
end

class Room < AR::Base
  has_many :users
end

class SetupRooms

  def initialize
    @users = User.all
    @rooms = Room.all
    @room_max_users = @users.size / @rooms.size
  end

  def setup
    groups = @users.in_groups_of(@room_max_users)
    # Now, How Can I fill rooms with users?
  end
end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You do not need the initialize method. Your setup can be written like this

```
def setup
  Room.all.each_with_index do |room, i|
    room.users = User.find(:all, :limit => room_max_users + i + 1)
    room.save 
  end
end
```

So this fills your rooms with users, based on their id in the database. Only the needed users are loaded at once so it should not be performance critical.

btw this method should be defined as a class method, perhaps on Room so you could invoke it like

```
class Room < AR::Base
  has_many :users

  def self.fill_with_users
    Room.all.each_with_index do |room, i|
      room.users = User.find(:all, :limit => room_max_users + i + 1)
      room.save 
    end
  end    
end


Room.fill_with_users
```

In this way you won't need your setup class as well.

Comment: There is no problem now for the number of users, but I keep this in mind for the future. Thanks Joe.

Comment: Yes, a class method has more sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
def setup
  groups = @users.in_groups_of(@room_max_users)
  @rooms.zip(groups).each do |room, group| # now "room" is a Room and "group" is an Array of Users
    group.delete_if { |user| user.nil? } # in_groups_of pads with nil if there are leftover spaces
    room.users = group
  end
end
```

Comment: Very compact and elegant. Thank you very much.

Comment: Joe had good points in his post about loading all the Rooms/Users at once; also, be aware that if you have, say 101 users and 20 rooms, it'll still return 5 as @room_max_users even though you really need 6. You could use `(@users.size.to_f / @rooms.size).ceil` instead.